# how to sort data based on two different (text and number) conditions in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sorting, select, sql-order-by

I have an `Emp` table, which has following data.

```
Eno    Ename   Location  Deptid
-------------------------------    
1      Alex    Delhi      10
2      John    Mumbai     10
.............................
```

Like this I have 1000 records, I need to sort them by `Deptid` column and `Location`.

The result after sort should be like this (If I sort by `deptid` and `location=Mumbai`):

If a deptid=10 has 300 records (of which 150-Delhi, 100-Mumbai, 50-chennai), then I should get all the records of mumbai (only with deptid=10) first, then other locations of same deptid and then records from other deptid.

Comment: Please show the desired results in tabular form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT Eno, Ename, Location, Deptid 
FROM employee
WHERE Deptid = 10 AND Location = 'Mumbai'
UNION ALL
SELECT Eno, Ename, Location, Deptid 
FROM employee
WHERE Deptid = 10 AND Location <> 'Mumbai'
UNION ALL
SELECT Eno, Ename, Location, Deptid 
FROM employee
WHERE Deptid <> 10
```

An Order by will probably screw it up, unless you add another column like

```
SELECT Eno, Ename, Location, Deptid 
FROM (
SELECT Eno, Ename, Location, Deptid, 1 OrderBy
FROM employee
WHERE Deptid = 10 AND Location = 'Mumbai'
UNION ALL
SELECT Eno, Ename, Location, Deptid, 2 OrderBy 
FROM employee
WHERE Deptid = 10 AND Location <> 'Mumbai'
UNION ALL
SELECT Eno, Ename, Location, Deptid, 3 OrderBy 
FROM employee
WHERE Deptid <> 10) a
ORDER BY OrderBy, Deptid, Location
```

Comment: The first query is workin fine, in the above result table I need top 200 rows.(In which the EmpId is selected randomly)..I have tried usin random newid(), but it is not working

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT Eno, Ename, Location, Deptid 
FROM employee
WHERE Deptid = 10
ORDER BY CASE deptid WHEN 10 THEN 0 ELSE deptid END, 
         CASE location WHEN 'Mumbai' THEN 1 WHEN 'Delhi' THEN 2 WHEN 'Chennai' THEN 3 END
```

**OR**

If you want data only for `deptid = 10` then use below query:

```
SELECT Eno, Ename, Location, Deptid 
FROM employee
WHERE Deptid = 10
ORDER BY deptid, CASE location WHEN 'Mumbai' THEN 1 WHEN 'Delhi' THEN 2 WHEN 'Chennai' THEN 3 END
```

Comment: But, I need to select all the department records not just(deptid=10). For example I have three deptids(10,20,30)..In deptid=10 records I need all the records of mumbai first, then all other city records, then all other department records..

Comment: @user3116746 For that you have to write case statement as per you need in ORDER BY. It will give you the result as per your need

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
SELECT Eno, Ename, Location, Deptid 
FROM Emp
ORDER BY  DeptId, Location desc
```

if I understand your requirement.. otherwise please explain it more detail

Comment: This will return records by location wise alphabatically, but I need a particular location of the department should come first(ex: all records of Mumbai of deptid=10), then other locations of the same department, then other department records..